# LoopTools addon curve option bug? Not working

Tags: add-on

[image]

Hi guys, this is the most frustrating thing I've come across lately. I select a few vertices and hit the curve button in LoopTools feature menu, and nothing happens. Sometimes it magically starts working, but most of the time it doesn't. Does anyone know why this is happening. I'd appreciate if you can try it in your blender and see if it works for you or not.

Comment: I never used it, seems a bit capricious, but it looks like it works if you cut your shape with some edges on the X axis

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out, I figured out that's where the problem lies, my vertices needs to be connected to the other side via edges on X axis. I posted a screenshot as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @moonboots for pointing the problem out, for some reason, it only works if you have a symmetrical topolgy, i.e you need to have edges on both axis. Below image is an example of topology on which this feature works : 
[image]